# How to check if dropdownlist contains 0 or is empty in asp.net using c#?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I have a dropdown list that has multiple values that i am getting from my stored procedure. But there can be a case that my dropdown remains empty. so in that case i want the user to manually input the value. Can it be possible? If yes how? thanks.

Comment: can you provide a code sample?

Comment: can i use this:  if (ddl.Items == null)
            {
                txt.Enabled = true;
            }

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
if (ddl.Items.Count == 0) { txt.Enabled = true; }
```